# Profiling of function with small execution time using %prun

Tags: python, profiling, ipython, execution-time

How can I do the profiling of functions in python which have very low execution time? I am getting 0 in most of the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a loop around it to run it some large number of times, like 10^6, so it takes at least several seconds.

Then the method I use to see how time is spent is [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771).